# Does PayPal Rest API have the classic useraction equivalent

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to skip the 2 step confirmation process using the PayPal REST Api?

I've successfully implemented the standard process using the PayPal REST api, which takes the user to the PayPal site where they enter their credentials and then get presented with the order summary with the option to "continue"  With the text - "youre almost done. You will confirm your payment on xxxx store".

Is there a way we can skip this step - so not returning the user to my site where they then again have to review the order and select "make payment", but rather display the "pay now" button at PayPal, which will execute payment?

I've searched, and the classic API seems to handle this by adding the url parameter, useraction commit.  If only I could find an equivalent for the REST api.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I got an answer from the PayPal support.

TL;DR: Just append `&useraction=commit` to the approval_url.

They told me the REST API redirection URL is a regular Express Checkout redirection URL and therefore you can use the same parameter.

If you do a payment API call like:

```sh
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
-H "Content-Type:application/json"
-H "Authorization:Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE"
-d '{
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency":"USD",
            "total":"12"
        },
        "description":"creating a payment"
    }],
    "payer": {
        "payment_method":"paypal"
    },
    "intent":"sale",
    "redirect_urls": {
        "cancel_url":"https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/curl?cancel=true",
        "return_url":"https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/curl?success=true"
    }
   }'
```

You will get the following response:

```json
{
   "id":"PAY-XYZ",
   "create_time":"2015-02-26T15:14:27Z",
   "update_time":"2015-02-26T15:14:28Z",
   "state":"created",
   "intent":"sale",
   "payer":{
      "payment_method":"paypal",
      "payer_info":{
         "shipping_address":{

         }
      }
   },
   "transactions":[
      {
         "amount":{
            "total":"12.00",
            "currency":"USD",
            "details":{
               "subtotal":"12.00"
            }
         },
         "description":"creating a payment",
         "related_resources":[

         ]
      }
   ],
   "links":[
      {
         "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XYZ",
         "rel":"self",
         "method":"GET"
      },
      {
         "href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-FOOBAR",
         "rel":"approval_url",
         "method":"REDIRECT"
      },
      {
         "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XYZ/execute",
         "rel":"execute",
         "method":"POST"
      }
   ]
}
```

In this response you get the approval url

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-FOOBAR
```

and you just have to programmatically extend it with the parameter `&useraction=commit`.

So you redirect your user to

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-FOOBAR&useraction=commit
```

Examples are from [the PayPal Developer Tools](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/curl?interactive=ON&env=sandbox).

Comment: The [Experience Profile docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/#definition-flow_config) seem to hint that it may be possible to achieve this with `"flow_config": { "user_action": "commit" }` in the future. But this is the only correct way at this time.

Comment: NOT working for me. The amount is being instantaneously transferred from buyer to merchant account but the transaction/activity is not showing up either on Buyer of Merchant dashboard

Answer (score 0):

This use case does exist on the REST side of things, but currently only available via the Mobile SDKs.  For more details look into https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/

When users are paying with PayPal in web, redirection to PayPal is still necessary in the REST ecosystem.