# Paypal PHP REST API - No Payment Value Shown At Checkout

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I am very new to the PayPal API and REST request/responses. As such, I have been trying to follow along with online samples (mostly from GitHub) about how to use PayPal's REST Api to process payments.

However, I have encountered a problem. When I click on the link that is generated, I am successfully redirected to PayPal's site. However, at the checkout page, there is nothing that indicates the amount of the purchase. What might the issue be? Thanks!

[image]

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';

use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency("USD");
$amount->setTotal('5.55');

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)->setDescription("Purchase from Leisurely Diversion")->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

$redirectURLs = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectURLs->setReturnUrl("http://localhost/leisurelydiversion/confirmation.php")->setCancelUrl("http://localhost/leisurelydiversion/confirmation.php");

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")->setPayer($payer)->setTransactions(array($transaction))->setRedirectUrls($redirectURLs);

try {
$payment->create($apiContext);
} catch(Exception $e) {
echo "<h2> Error Sending Payment! $e</h2>";
}

$url = $payment->getApprovalLink();
echo $url;
?>
```

Comment: Having same issue. The amount is being instantaneously transferred from buyer to merchant account but the transaction/activity is not showing up either on Buyer of Merchant dashboard

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an item list to the payment:
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/OrderCreateUsingPayPal.html

You can also change the action by appending `&useraction=commit` to the approval url:
[Does PayPal Rest API have the classic useraction equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956117/does-paypal-rest-api-have-the-classic-useraction-equivalent)

Comment: NOT working for me. The amount is being instantaneously transferred from buyer to merchant account but the transaction/activity is not showing up either on Buyer of Merchant dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help**

```
$item = new Item();
$item->setSku('Product Id');
$item->setName('Product Name');
$item->setPrice('5.55');
$item->setCurrency('USD');
$item->setQuantity(1);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item));

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setItemList($itemList);
$transaction->setAmount($amount);
```