# How to remove message "You'll be able to review your order before you complete your purchase" from PayPal payment page?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Is there any way to remove following message from the PayPal payment page?

> You'll be able to review your order before you complete your purchase.

I'm using REST API without the Express Checkout Custom Button. The payment happens AFTER the order is submitted so  this message makes no sense and is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if anyone still needs this, but here's a link to a similar question on GitHub that has been answered as of March 2, 2018. If you add 'commit: true' when calling your paypal.Button.Render() function, it will switch to a more "Pay Now" mode, and remove the "...review your order..." text from the window. Hope that helps someone. Here's the link:

https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/554

Comment: Thanks for posting your find, it helped me out. They have an example of this in their latest documentation as well now that I've gone back and checked. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/integrate/#1-get-the-code

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to this is that it is not possible without PayPal fixing it. I have googled extensively and the only reference to this issue I could find was this 4-day-old post. It had 3 people (including myself) responding and saying that they had the same issue, 2 of which have now been deleted because they were not "answers" (why the 3rd is still there as of this writing I don't know).

If at least 4 people have found this to be a problem in the last 4 days and there is no sign of anyone with the issue before that, that leads me to believe it is a recent issue (and there will be more people discovering it in coming days).

Also, this PayPal help page details how to change your "Continue" button to a "Pay Now" button. 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/#display-a-pay-now-button

It does not mention the "You'll be able to review your order before you complete your purchase." phrase at all. It seems like if it were possible to remove that on it's own, it would be documented in the same place.

I tried to submit a support ticket to PayPal at 
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask
But that form appears to not be working either. I just get "submitting..." with the animation spinning indefinitely. Perhaps someone can get it to work. Not sure how responsive they are. Or maybe they will just fix it eventually on their own.

Note to moderators: While this is not a definitive answer, I believe I have at the very least provided a reasoned theory, sharing my Google research and referencing the PayPal help page that, it seems, would provide the answer. Hopefully that's enough that it won't be deleted. I do feel that this answer could be helpful to someone who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just asked PayPal for instructions on how to remove the text and was told:

"There is not a way to update this on your website. The purpose of the Express Checkout is so that your customers can sign in to an existing PayPal account or can check out as a guest. PayPal always tries to give the opportunity for the customers to cancel the payment prior to initiating it. Please let us know if you have any further issues."

So in answer to your question, there is not currently a way to remove that text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suffering with the same issue, this would be great to be able to remove as the button is set to "Pay Now" at PayPal, which leads the customer to believe they click this button and payment is taken...? Or am I not thinking this through clearly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing this issue. [image of the checkout experience.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi24q.png) I even went to the trouble of creating a payment experience with the user action to commit so that the "Continue" button says "Pay Now" `"flow_config":{"user_action":"commit"}`

I don't understand why the "You’ll be able to review your order before you complete your purchase." line remains, even though the button says Pay Now. [This link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payment-experience/#create-web-experience-profile) suggests that the commit action means you can "complete the payment without additional interaction from the buyer." This seems contrary to the message displayed below the Pay Now button to the buyer.

I'm using this api : developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/ in postman to create the experience, then creating payments using the experience ID that paypal responds with.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is kind of old but if you append `&useraction=commit` to the approval URL that you redirect the user to, the message will go away and the button will change to "Pay Now." The user will then be redirected back to the return URL you provided after they click the button.

---

See also:

- [Does PayPal Rest API have the classic useraction equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956117/does-paypal-rest-api-have-the-classic-useraction-equivalent)